# C# .Net Change value of variable after a certain period

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get a function in ASP.Net's C# to work.. Here's the case,

I've got a code to generate a string out, and I want that string to be valid for only 1 minute.

After 1 minute the string should be replaced by another string which will be hardcoded by us.

Is there any way to do this WITHOUT interacting with the database?

Comment: Database? What database? Do you mean "webserver"?

Comment: you are going to have to give a lot more details of what you are trying to do

Comment: I really, really don't understand. A variable, as long as it is in memory, will stay the last value you assigned to it. So if you do a timer and change its value after a minute, it will do just that.

Comment: Can you please explain what "string to be valid" means and what 1 minute refers to (page in a browsers, code on server, something else)?

Comment: I suspect he wants a javascript function that will change the value of a text string after one minute, with the value of both strings determined dynamically on the server when the page is sent to the browser. Or something.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I suggest. You'll obviously need to update the front end, but it should be easy to plug in.

```
public class MagicString()
{
    DateTime creationDate;
    private string _text;

    public MagicString(string text)
    {
        this.text = _text;
        creationDate = dateTime.
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (creationDate.AddMinutes(1) > DateTime.Now)
        {
            return HARDCODEDSTRING;
        }
        else 
        {
            return _text;
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. good match to question as it asked... Awesome way to drive crazy the developer who have to debug code with such values :)